Why is backdrop-filter expensive on elements containing an animation?
When an element has a backdrop-filter and has anything animated within it, I see a huge amount of CPU and GPU usage in Chrome. This doesn't make sense to me, because a backdrop-filter only needs to be recalculated when things behind it change.
Take this example:


@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<div style="
      background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #fff,
        #fff 10px,
        #aaa 10px,
        #aaa 20px
      );
      height: 100px;
    ">
  <div style="backdrop-filter: blur(3px)">
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red">
      <span style="
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: green;
            animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
          "></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



That page has:

An outer div with a pinstripe background.
Within that, a div with background-filter: blur. It shows blurred pinstripes.
And within that, a green div with animated opacity.

Here's what I expect to happen to render this. We'll get three compositing layers:

Layer 1: the outer div, with a pinstripe background.
Layer 2: the div with the background-filter.
Layer 3: the div with animated opacity.

Animating opacity is supposed to be cheap: it should cause a compositing step once per frame. There should be no layout/reflow or painting.
I do not expect the background-filter to have any performance impact. The blurred background should only be re-calculated when the layers beneath it change - which doesn't happen, since it's just a static background beneath it. The GPU process should be at around 5% CPU and 1% GPU (the amount used when there is no background-filter).
And indeed, this is all what Chrome dev tools claims is happening. The layers tool shows those three layers, and a 10-second performance profile shows 0ms on rendering, 0ms on painting, and claims the GPU is essentially idle.
And yet macOS Activity Monitor shows much more activity in the GPU process. Chrome's GPU process uses 20% CPU and 17% GPU on my M2 MacBook.
What is it doing? Is the backdrop-filter being re-calculated? Why? And how can I find the answers with Chrome dev tools?

To analyze in Chrome Dev Tools, check the performance panel.

chrome://tracing/ using the "Rendering" settings shows a lot of activity. No time to dig in there myself, but certainly they mark the frame as dirty, for some reason. You might get better returns by opening an issue to their tracker though.

This code snippet isn't expensive for my CPU but it's using 6.5 MB of GPU (as Chrome's Task Manager says).

can someone please detail where exactly this is observed, i.e. a significant change in cpu/gpu when animating an element inside vs when animating an element behide
